# mktime returns incorrect value

Tags: c, time, mktime

I'de like to use `mktime` on a microcontroller (or at least use 32-bit wide timestamps). I added the needed files from [avr libc source files](https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/tree/master/avr-libc) (in Atmel Studio 7, time functions aren't available), didn't change the algoritms. But for 2016. 06. 08. 23:34:00 (UTC+1, EU dst), `mktime` returns `518736960`, but it should return `1465425240`.

```
set_zone(ONE_HOUR);
set_dst(eu_dst);
struct tm myTime;
myTime.tm_sec = 0;
myTime.tm_min = 36;
myTime.tm_hour = 23;
myTime.tm_mday = 8;
myTime.tm_mon = 5;
myTime.tm_year = 116;
myTime.tm_isdst = ONE_HOUR;
time_t tim = mktime(&myTime);
```

What am I doing wrong? These functions should work fine.

Comment: "standard library"? No. This is a C library implementation that contains some non-standard functions. We don't know what other non-portable behavior lies under the hood.

Comment: `set_zone`, `ONE_HOUR`, `set_dst`, and `eu_dst` are non-standard.

Comment: `tm::tm_isdst` is positive if DST is in effect, zero if not and negative if no information is available -  serring it to`ONE_HOUR` makes little sense.  Omit the non-standard parts - `set_zone()` and `set_dst()` and set `tm_isdst==0` and see what the result is.  If the time you are setting is the time you wan't (i.e. is already adjusted) you don't need timezone or DST adjustments.

Comment: Did you compile [this file](https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/master/avr-libc/libc/time/mktime.c)?

Comment: Better to _first_ `struct tm myTime = {0};` as `struct tm` may have other implementation define fields not set by OP's code.

Comment: @Clifford without them, mktime return 518744160, the difference is very small.

Comment: @wallyk Yes, I added dst_pointer.c, eu_dst.h, gmtime_r.c, isLeap.c, localtime_r.c, mk_gtime.c, mktime.c, set_dst.c, set_zone.c, time.h, and utc_offset.c into my project, all of them are compiled.

Comment: Post the code that shows the "`mktime` returns 518736960`" as the problem may be there.

Comment: @chux I've already posted the code.

Comment: @klenium : My suggestion was not intended to fix the problem but to allow you to discount the possibility of errors in these functions in order that you can be sure that it is `mktime()` that is the issue - that's how you investigate software bugs - divide and conquer.

Comment: Interesting that `time.h` uses non-standard `struct tm`.  (Expected fields to be type `int`)  Makes one wonder what other non-standard time details exist.

Comment: @klenium None of this posted code shows how `tim` was determine to have the value `518736960`.  That is the code requested.  AFAIK, `tim` does has the expected value and the method use to display it is at fault.

Comment: @chux : Given the tiny memories typically on AVR, a compliant implementation would be expensive. User beware!

Comment: @Clifford, the point is, how did OP determine the value of `tim`?  BTW: good compilers analyzes the formats used in `printf()` and use a selective implementation.  With simple format like integer to text conversion, the code is not long and not expensive.

Comment: @chux : In my comment I was referring only to your point about the definition of `struct tm`.  Regarding the presentation of code, I agree with you completely, but it is academic now perhaps, I found the answer initially by intuition having converted the values to Unix epoch time, and then by *reading the documentation* ;-)

Comment: @Clifford I too had suspected a different day epoch, but discounted that  since with a difference between expectation and actual was obviously not a multiple of 100 (and hence not a multiple of 3600*24), for the epoch to be wrong, the expected had to be wrong too for the given timestamp.  I had assumed only 1 oops on OP's part.  IAC, read the fantastic manual it a good idea.

Comment: Note that the value is "unexpected" not "incorrect".

Comment: Time zone is incorrect. Should be UTC-1 to get 23.34.00.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

518736960 corresponds to *Unix epoch time* 09 Jun 1986 21:36:00; it looks to me as if this implementation uses a different epoch, starting 1 January 2000 rather then 1 January 1970.

The time difference is then attributable to the TZ and DST offsets.  The out-by-one date difference is attributable to the fact that 2000 was not a leap-year, but 1970 was.

---

**Edit:**

The documentation [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html) clearly states that the epoch start is 2000:

> Though not specified in the standard, it is often expected that time_t is a signed integer representing an offset in seconds from Midnight Jan 1 1970... i.e. 'Unix time'. This implementation uses an unsigned 32 bit integer offset from Midnight Jan 1 2000. The use of this 'epoch' helps to simplify the conversion functions, while the 32 bit value allows time to be properly represented until Tue Feb 7 06:28:15 2136 UTC. The macros UNIX_OFFSET and NTP_OFFSET are defined to assist in converting to and from Unix and NTP time stamps.

There is no standard for epoch nor the specific underlying width or signedness of `time_t`.  However if you round-trip the result of `mktime()` with `localtime()` for example using the *same library* it will produce a correct result.  One library or system's `time_t` value need not be compatible with another's, so exchanging a `time_t` value between systems is slightly problematic.

In this case you could convert to a recognised defacto standard by adding `UNIX_OFFSET` or `NTP_OFFSET` and if necessary ensure that any corresponding adjustment is performed on the receiving system  The principle is similar to the principle of *[network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking)* for example for exchanging data between systems with different endinaness by using an agreed intermediate representation (which is as it happens also something to consider when exchanging  a `time_t`).

Often it is simpler to exchange a string of a specified format (such as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) to avoid epoch, data type and endianness differences. On te other hand conversion to and from string representations is more expensive than purely arithmetic manipulation.